# C Loop : printing India Map

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm editting this questions b'coz I'm not allowed to add new questions.

I found this program doing awesome printing but can't understand how it works. Please help me understand the logic behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a,b,c;
   int count = 1;
   for (b=c=10; a="- FIGURE?, UMKC,XYZHello Folks,\
                   TFy!QJu ROo TNn(ROo)SLq SLq ULo+\
                   UHs UJq TNn*RPn/QPbEWS_JSWQAIJO^\
                   NBELPeHBFHT}TnALVlBLOFAkHFOuFETp\
                   HCStHAUFAgcEAelclcn^r^r\\tZvYxXy\
                   T|S~Pn SPm SOn TNn ULo0ULo#ULo-W\
                   Hq!WFs XDt!" [b++ +21]; )
         for(; a-- > 64 ; )
              putchar (( ++c == 'Z') ? c = c /9 : 33^b&1);
  return 0;
}
```

Output ScreenShot is

[image]

Comment: Are you using TranslateMessage() in your message loop?

Comment: yes sir, my message loop is:
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) { 
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
          TranslateMessage(&msg);
          DispatchMessage(&msg); 
  }
}

Comment: Lots of strange things here. For starters, you should never need to cast function pointers; if you do, the compiler is trying to tell you that the function signature is incorrect. So this code is wrong: `reinterpret_cast<DLGPROC>(DlgProc)`. Second, there is no need to set focus to the dialog in response to the `WM_INITDIALOG` message. That's already done for you.

Comment: You changed the question completely. Please do not do this!

Comment: @Cong Xu, Sorry sir, but i've no other option left to post this question.

Answer (score 1):

The tab key will normally be swallowed by the dialog manager as it's used to move the focus from one control to another (i.e. the `IsDialogMessage` call that the `DialogBox` function calls as part of its internal message loop will filter out the tab key press and not let it through to your dialog procedure).

There are a couple of ways I can think of you can get around this, but I would suggest that you should probably pick another key to open/close the dialog, since tab already has a well-known and well-defined meaning in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the "EndDialog" description of the msdn it states:

> EndDialog does not destroy the dialog box immediately. Instead, it sets a flag and allows the dialog box procedure to return control to the system. The system checks the flag before attempting to retrieve the next message from the application queue. If the flag is set, the system ends the message loop, destroys the dialog box, and uses the value in nResult as the return value from the function that created the dialog box.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?